# Adding Tizen native application at framework level

Tags: tizen, tizen-native-app

Is it possible to add Tizen native application at framework level as a inbuilt application

Can any one give ideas about this

Comment: Probably you will have to create whole custom image

Answer (score 0):

With Tizen SDK IDE you can make platform application:

`File > New > Project > Tizen > Tizen Platform Project`

It builds to rpm package. Of course you need admin rights to build it and to install it on Tizen device.

Also, do not spam the same question over and over again, please.